# where can I find rhx_gis from instagram response page?

Tags: web-crawler, instagram

I've been using a instagram crawler for my own, using post requests in a infinite-scroll-like algorithm,
using

```
md5("{}:{}".format(rhxGis,LOADS.replace('TAG_STRING', targethash).replace('AFTER_STRING',end_cursor)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

this as my x-instagram-gis header, as many of you may already know.

but since 2019/5/16, rhx_gis value is not bound to _sharedData anymore, so I cannot use the crawler.

I've been looking for rhx_gis in all of the scripts that came along with the response, but nothing could be seen but an uglified function.

Has anybody found a way to get the gis value or a new x-instagram-gis hashing algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can skip rhxGis from md5 and it will work

Comment: I've never thought this would work and it actually did. The hash is not same as one the instagram web app actually sends to its server, but it seems the instagram server does not take it seriously. Thanks!